# Sharing LADSPA filter output with different processes

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

On a Linux + ALSA microcomputer platform I'm trying to filter my microphone input for all my applications through a LADSPA filter. The filter takes a certain amount of CPU processing.

Below is an example of my /etc/asound.conf

```
pcm.filtered_capture{
type ladspa
slave.pcm "dsnoop_48000"
path "/usr/lib/ladspa"
capture_plugins[{
    label computationally_heavy_filter
}]
}

pcm.dsnoop_48000 {
type dsnoop
slave.pcm "hw:0,0"
}
```

I've noticed `arecord -D filtered_capture` linearly increases per command I run, and it's much higher than what file I/O would use. Is there any way to set up my ALSA plugins so that the audio PCM data that is getting shared is happening after the filter instead of before?